# How can I solve this using Knockout JS?

Tags: html, knockout.js

I have the following code, I am trying to get an id in the SPAN and it is not accepting values in any type of tag that is located inside ....

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12" id="contenedorListaTarea">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs align-items-lg-start mb-1" data-bind="foreach: loterias">
        
        <li class="nav-item" name="loteria" data-bind="click:namerjarClickLoteria">
            <a class="nav-link fontSizeTab" data-bind="text: nombre,style: { backgroundColor: color},attr:{id:id+nombreCorto}">
                <span data-bind="attr:{id:nombreCorto}" >0.00</span>
            </a>

        </li>
        
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly your problem is that any tag placed in `<a>` tag is to being rendered. The reason for that to happen is that your `<a>` tag is using `text: nombre` binding which is replacing anything you have put inside it.

I removed that binding and `<span>` started to appear in it with working `attr` binding.

```js
var viewModel = function() {
  this.loterias = ko.observableArray([
    {
      nombre: 'test',
      color: 'red',
      id: 'test-id',
      nombreCorto: 1,
      namerjarClickLoteria: function(){      
      }
    },
    {
      nombre: 'test',
      color: 'green',
      id: 'test-id',
      nombreCorto: 2,
      namerjarClickLoteria: function(){      
      }
    }
  ]);
  
  return this;
}


ko.applyBindings(viewModel(), $('#contenedorListaTarea')[0]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12" id="contenedorListaTarea">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs align-items-lg-start mb-1" data-bind="foreach: loterias">
        
        <li class="nav-item" name="loteria" data-bind="click:namerjarClickLoteria">
            <a class="nav-link fontSizeTab" data-bind="style: { backgroundColor: color},attr:{id:id+nombreCorto}">
                <span data-bind="attr:{id:nombreCorto}" >0.00</span>
            </a>

        </li>
        
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: exactly, but i really need both, in the end what i did was add the <span><span>, with javascript to make it work for me

the name of the lottery, and the span <span>5:00<span> that indicates the remaining minutes for closing